# Can my Node JS app access data of my Android app with Firebase?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using a nodejs app with FCM to send notifications to an Android app. The problem is that I want to send notifications for specified users and each of them has different registered tokens. I can make the Android app upload the token information to an Android project on Firebase, but how can I make my nodejs app read the token information from the same project?

It seems Firebase only support database for separate platforms (e.g., Android, ios, web). Is there a way to create a shared database that can be accessed by both Android and web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to use the same database in Android/ios/web:

1. Click on your project

Then in the Overview Page Click <kbd>add another app</kbd>:

[image]

Then click on the app you want:

[image]

and follow the setup, all apps under one project will share the same database.

You can also use FCM with cloud functions to send notifications.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: This is what I need! It's straightforward but for some reason, I couldn't find any information online. But thanks!!

Comment: I did upvote your answer but my reputation is not enough to show the it. Sorry about that :(

Comment: Just upvoted! For some reason, I get 18 now. I was 7 or something before.